# Rendering became grey after I added an object, not a clipping problem, screenshot attached

Tags: rendering

My animation rendered great until I added a blender object to it, it became grey and is showing the added object as a plane object. Camera clip end is set at 4000m so not the cause of the problem. Any idea please?[image: screenshot]

Comment: I found out even though the image is grey and not visible in the render view, when I actually rendered the animation it came out properly without any problem!

Comment: Your render looks like you hit "Viewport Render Image" not actual Camera view Render. Render on your screenshot is from top view with two orange lines and dots (I gues image planes with origins). Did you render via Render > Render Image (F12) or from lower header View > Viewport Render Image?

Comment: I used the the Viewport render image, but it doesnt seem to work properly in that case since the actual render was fine.

Answer (score 2):

From informations you provided:

- I don't think your render became grey because you added an object
- Grey render in your screenshot is probably **Viewport Render Image**
  (see [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/viewport_render.html?) for more info)
- Fact that your render is OK now, with this kind of rendering, is probably because you switched viewport draw mode from "Solid" to "Render", but it has nothing to do with regular camera rendering it is still only viewport render.

[image]

- To get proper camera render use shortcut **F12** (or use this function via top row menu **Render > Render Image**)

[image]